# For facebook analytics sdk I am getting this error Can anyone please tell me fast how to solve this?

Tags: android, analytics, fbsdk

**Error:(12, 0) Could not find method implementation() for arguments [com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler. Open File**

```
buildscript { 
    repositories { 
    google() jcenter() mavenCentral() 
    } 
    dependencies { 
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1' implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    } 
} 
allprojects { 
    repositories { google() jcenter() mavenCentral() 
    } 
} 

task clean(type: Delete) { 
    delete rootProject.buildDir 
}
```

Comment: Please add the proper code for better understanding

Comment: buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Comment: Edit your question for more clearification